# Proper use of wp_localize_script?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

I want to pass an array of data to my script `mygaloochart_script` located in the `chart.js` file.

Here's what I tried:

```
//I'm no using $atts directly because of reasons
$dataToBePassed = array (
                'chart' => $atts['chart'],
                'element' => $atts['element'],
                'elementtype' => $atts['elementtype'],
                'title' => $atts['title']
);

function pw_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('googlechart', 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mygaloochart_script', plugins_url('chart.js', __FILE__), array('googlechart'));
    wp_localize_script('mygaloochart_script', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed);
}

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pw_load_scripts');
```

The first line of `chart.js` is `console.log(php_vars.chart);`, however nothing appears in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` should be the action name, I guess `wp_enqueue_script` is the mistake you have done while asking a question.

Comment: Why are you enqueue-ing `googlechart` outside of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook?

Comment: Edited with your remarks, but still the same issue.
@bravokeyl I think t's being enqueued in the `wp_enqueue_script('mygaloochart_script', plugins_url('chart.js', __FILE__), array('googlechart'));`

Comment: my guess is `chart.js` is not being enqueued. On the other hand `$dataToBePassed` is outside the scope of the function , it gives you null.

Comment: What do you mean it's not enqueued? How should I enqueue it?

Comment: No I can't see it in my source code, but I fail to see how I enqueued it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

How does your `function pw_load_scripts()` know about the existence of `$dataToBePassed`? Is the variable global? Looking at the code you've got, I'm guessing that, as far as `wp_localize_script()` is concerned, `$dataToBePassed` is a local variable, and it's probably `null`.

Comment: I solved it. The issue was... `$datatoBePassed` should be `$dataToBePassed`